# Restrict url to one segment, even when page or post is nested

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I use nested/hierarchic pages purely for organizational purposes in the admin but on the main site I don't want a nested url structure. So if the page structure is /page/another-page/and-another-page, the url should only read http://domain.com/and-another-page.

Is this possible? And if so, how? Should this be solved with a url rewrite?

Thanks in advance!

PS: this is not used for funny SEO business or anything. I just want to read the url like Wikipedia which always has a single url segment. I'm building a wiki like site but want to be able to nest pages so I can group them together more easily in the admin.

Comment: A solution per plugin is given here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56380/remove-parent-slug-for-child-pages